# Option value property is not recognised by the browser

Tags: javascript

I am transferring a project from Codepen to my computer. When I load it from my computer I get an error here:

```
var get=document.getElementById('workTime'); //get the value of the Wokrktime

var endPoint=((2*(parseInt(get.value)))/60)+1.5;
```

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null. The error is for the last line. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Either element doesn't exist at all, or you are looking for it before it exists. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Assuming it's on the page when you call it, `get` returns a DOM node, which doesn't have a `value`.  But it does have a `innerHTML`.  Maybe that's what you're looking for?  Also, `get` is not a very good name for a variable.

Comment: Hmm..it works in my codepen project though: https://codepen.io/Ispaxan/pen/mqpWjM?editors=1011

Comment: codepen makes sure js executes after the html exists. If your js is in head then it executes before

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah, input will have value, sorry.  I think the first comment ^^ is worth looking into then.

Comment: I have put it at the end of the HTML document and it seems to work but the $( document ).ready() seems not to work for some reason.